# Add role dynamically without db while logging in in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

How can I add a role to a user at the time of log in based on his username. I think it can be accomplished using `yii\rbac\PhpManager` . I tried something like

```
$r=new PhpManager;
$r->init();
$r->createRole("1","admin");
$r->save();
$r->assign('1','admin');
```

where `1` is user id and `admin` is the intended role.

But I am getting an error

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException

Calling unknown method: yii\rbac\PhpManager::save()
```

What is the error here? or which is the right method?

Answer (score 3):

Do not call ->save, there is no save function for PHP manager, if you remove $r->save(); it should all work ok I believe.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-phpmanager.html

In the official docs they never call save() on anything
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html